# Hive on slave node

Tags: hive

I have a two node hadoop cluster one master and one slave.I need to install Hive now. Is it mandatory that I have to install it on the master node only? Or can I install it on the slave?

Answer (score 0):

You should install hive wherever you want to run your hive queries, whether it is a master or slave or both.

Moreover, if you have now the question that if you install hive on both nodes, how both the nodes will share the same metastore. The answer is, in hive-site.xml, you can configure connection details like below:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://metastore-server:9083,thrift://metastore-server2:9083</value>
</property>
```

There are several parameters required for setting up the jdbc connection for the hive metastore. Here is one of them - look for similar ones in the hive-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```